# When does the md5 hash of an .apk file change although affected by malware?

Tags: android, hash

I'm developing an app that detects malware by observing the change in the md5 check sum of that app's .apk file.Below are the steps i have followed

1) Downloaded some infected .apk files like "icalendar acbcad45094de7e877b656db1c28ada2.apk" and installed them on to the Android Emulator using adb.

2)Restarted the emulator and calculated the md5 check sum of all the apps.

3)Unfortunately,I could not observe any change in any of the .apk files md5 check sum.(I'm pretty much sure that the above mentioned icalendar.apk is a virus,I have checked it on "virus total").

What should i conclude from this? Are the apps not infected by any virus?(or) am not heading in the right direction?

Any Suggestions will be helpful